# column name is ambiguous mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have spent hours trying to select all rows from different tables and still no luck. I am getting:

```
column name firstname is ambiguous
```

The tables don't have any relationships, I just want to select all rows as I need the query for searching all tables for matching string. I have search bar.

Is there any nicer way to select all rows from multiple tables where the column numbers doesn't match. I have tried `UNION ALL` but it gives me an error. Please help

```
 $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 JOIN `table2` t2 ON joinitem.t1 = joinitem.t2 where firstname = ? ");
stmt->bind_param('s', $firstname);
echo $mydb->error;
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

try being specific in `WHERE` clause, like

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 
   JOIN `table2` t2 ON t1.joinitem = t2.joinitem
   WHERE t1.firstname = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

That error came up because you have the column `firstname` in both your tables. Without specifying which `firstname` you mean, SQL cannot tell whether you want the query to be based on table1's firstname or table2's firstname.

To make sure SQL knows which one you mean, prefix the column name with the table name.

Also, I believe the `JOIN` condition should be `tablename.joinitem` instead of `joinitem.tablename`.

Here is an example assuming the `firstname` you want is from `table2`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1` t1
JOIN `table2` t2 ON t1.joinitem = t2.joinitem
WHERE t2.firstname = ?
```

Comment: the error is gone but when I try to echo the rows `$result = $stmt->get_result();
var_dump($result);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 echo $row['firstname'];}` I get empty page

Comment: I'm new to PDO, so I'm just taking a guess. I think the problem is with `$stmt->get_result()`. Try to use `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. For reference, see [this link](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).